# Recursion for finding a 6 in an array

Tags: java, recursion

So i played around with this and ultimately made it work. I have a question as to why I need a "return" array6(nums, index + 1); instead of just making it a recursive call array6(nums, index +1).

```
public boolean array6(int[] nums, int index) {
boolean contains = false;
  if( nums.length == 0)
  {
    contains = false;
  } else {
    if(nums[index] == 6)
    {
      contains = true;
    } else {
      if(index + 1 == nums.length)
      {
        contains = false;
      } else {
        return array6(nums, index + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return contains;
}
```

Comment: return array6... is making a recursive call to array6() and returning the result of that call. If that doesn't make sense, see if you can find some recursive implementations of factorial so you can wrap your brain around it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic question on `recursion`.

**A simple explanation:**
Imagine that in every recursive call you branch out, at the end when you finish your job, you want to return to every branched the result you got further in the branch.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `return array6` - however you do need to somehow signal back what the method you called recursively found.

You can do that either by doing the return, as in your code, or by doing `contains = array6(nums, index + 1);

Otherwise even if one of your recursive calls find a match you will still return false back up the chain after the first return of true.

Answer (score 0):

Let's pretend you don't use return, your code would look like this:

```
 } else {
       array6(nums, index + 1);
 }
```

What if that call to array6 DID find the 6? You won't know because the answer is whatever array6 returns so you either store it in another variable (such as `contains` and return it later) or return it directly using the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

So each function call, it gets allocated a bit on the stack. Each recursive call, it gets creates a link to the next function call on the stack.

NOTE: This following isn't entirely accurate as I simplify a lot of the back end stuff.

So to step it out,
sample array { 2 , 2 , 6 }
[call# , return]

First call, we start at index 0

[1, -returns new call-] // No 6 yet, calls mid way

[1, [2, -returns new call-]] // No 6 yet

[1, [2, [3 , -finds 6 at index '2' and returns-]]]

[1, [2, -3rd call returns 'true']]

[1, -2nd call returns 'true']

Answer is true.

Also, a shorter way for that problem:

```
public boolean array6(int[] nums, int index) {
    if( index < 0 || index > nums.length){ // index is out of bounds or not found
        return false;
    } else if( nums[index] == 6 ){
        return true; // If we see it, return true.
    } else {
        return array6( nums , index + 1 );
    }
}
```